# Function to find cloest to zero not returning negatives - R

Tags: r, min

I'm doing some linear regression and testing a bunch of data with a program I'm writing in **R**.

After implementing a linear model `lm()`, I get this:

`>>summary(model2)$coef[,3]`

```
(Intercept)         sex         fat       fiber     alcohol        chol
 19.2786166  -6.1693274   2.5304990   3.0357110   1.3205717  -0.8407960
```

To find the closet to zero, I'm doing this:

`mn <- min(abs(summary(model2)$coef[,3]-0))`

```
>> mn
[1] 0.840796
```

However, `mn` should be negative. How can I adjust my method to return the negative version?
(I need it to be negative because I square it after).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
closest.to.zero <- function(x) x[which.min(abs(x))]

closest.to.zero(summary(model2)$coef[,3])
```

Comment: Awesome. This works great and returns the negative. But I've just noticed that squaring a variable in R (c = c^2) doesn't return the negative anyway (unless you type the number like this -0.5678^2).

Comment: Why would you expect that squaring a negative number gives a negative number? If `x <- -3`, then `x^2` is `9` and that's the right result. R will tell you that `-3^2` is `-9` only because the `^` operator has higher precedence than the unary `-` operator, so `-3^2` is like doing `-(3^2)`.

Comment: I was checking as I went on my calculator. If you square it using the `x^2 button`, it returns a negative, but not if you type `-0.123*-0.123`. It totally slipped my mind that a negative multiplied by itself becomes a positive. Dumb moment. Thanks for highlighting that.

Comment: that's a pretty strange calculator if it gives negative values when squaring a floating-point number ...